# How can we display a message when certain type is selected in the dropdown in Shiny?

Tags: r, validation, shiny

I want to display a message like "For this Campaign only Audio can be selected" when users selects "Trend" from the Campaign dropdown and select other than Audio in the Campaign channel dropdown. This message should be displayed and rest of the program should not be executed.

Dropdown labels : Campaign and Campaign channel

I tried giving stopapp but it exits the Shiny app itself. I just want to display this. If user selects "Trend and "Audio" or any other Campaign and Campaign channel combination the rest of the logic should work.

The expected result is to display the message.

Comment: I think you're going to need to give a little more of an example, Anna ... a MWE would be useful. Are you talking a modal popup or just a message? On the console (logfile) or on the display? (Perhaps what you need is `shiny::showModal(shiny::modalDialog(...))`

Comment: I need to just display if "Trend" from Campaign and "Audio" from Campaign Channel is selected. Now, along with the message the other datatables are displayed below that.

Comment: Anna, you've provided small (complete) working example code for your other questions, can you do the same for this one please?

Answer (score 0):

As @r2evans has said, without seeing your code it'd be hard to tell you how to adjust it to stop the rest of the program from executing.

But for the popup message, does this achieve what you want:

```
observeEvent(c(input$Campaign, input$CampaignChannel), {
  if ( input$Campaign == "Trend" && input$CampaignChannel != "Audio" ){
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Important message",
      "For this campaign only Audio can be selected",
      easyClose = TRUE
    ))
  }
})
```